# Quantlib derivative valuation from zero curve

Tags: derivatives, python, quantlib, valuation

I have newly started with Quantlib-Python for valuing derivatives. In all the examples stated in this [bolg](http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/quantlib-python-tutorials-with-examples.html) or in other places, market quote is inserted and bootstrapping is done via individual rate helpers to create the zero curve.

Is there a way I can directly insert the zero rates in Quantlib so that it can  interpolate from the zero rates and give the final NPV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the zero rates, you can construct the zero curve using the set of maturities (dates) and zero rates values, in addition to a day count convention in this way:

```
import QuantLib as ql
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = ql.Date(26, 7, 2018)
dates = [ql.Date(26, 7, 2019), ql.Date(26, 7, 2020), ql.Date(26, 7, 2030)]
zero_rates = [0.03, 0.04, 0.06]
zero_curve = ql.ZeroCurve(dates, zero_rates, ql.Actual365Fixed())
```

I don't understand what NPV you are looking for though? The NPV will be related to an instrument, not to a zero curve.

Comment: I meant valuation, not looking for NPV, it was a mistake, thanks

Comment: Welcome. Glad I was able to help!